# Using C# classes from the MSDN

Tags: c#, msdn

This might sound like a really stupid question but is it possible to use the c# classes documented in the MSDN? And if so how do I use them into my application?

For example: I want to read information from a BitLocker password (I know the password) protected USB drive using C# code and (if I understand correctly) the [Win32_EncryptableVolume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376483(v=vs.85).aspx) class allows me to unlock the USB drive with a passcode, however the problem is that I can't figure out how to actually use the class. Is that even possible?

Comment: of course its possible. you need to learn how to code.... so download Visual Studio community edition and start coding! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx

Comment: That's a WMI class, not a C# one, but there's some C# code in the page comments which should get you started.

Comment: Note that many of the examples on MSDN use poor coding practices.  For example, I have seen countless examples that don't make use of the `using` keyword to ensure that resources are properly cleaned up.  The examples can be a good starting point at times, but just copy and paste into your own code is not always a good idea.

Comment: Side note: "class" is used in many languages with very similar syntax - you should make sure you understand what language the code is in - C++, C#, Java, TypeScript have very similar syntax but using samples in one language directly with another language is hard at least (and sometimes not even possible i.e. with browser/server code).